# is there a Laravel-4 equivlant of .NET Bundles

Tags: javascript, asp.net, laravel-4, bundle

In ASP.NEt there are Bundles which allow someone to combine java script files into one bundle which can be included in views, instead of including the individual files.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mainJs")
      .Include("~/Scripts/mainSite.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/helperStuff.js");

 <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mainJs") %>
```

Is there a Laravel 4 equivalent?

Comment: I'm looking for this too!

Comment: Is tag laravel-4 relevant?